# Is "enabled?" method available on Watir and/or Page-Objects for a link?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir, page-object-gem

Yesterday i was working on determining is this link was or not enabled, waiting until enabled in order to click it. I'm using Cucumber + Ruby + Watir + Page-Object gem. The link is very similar to:

```
<a id="the_link"  href="#" disabled="disabled">Proceed with your order</a>
```

Once you fill some fields, the link is enabled and the source changes to:

```
<a id="the_link"  href="#">Proceed with your order</a>
```

The idea is to wait until the link is enabled in this way, which works with buttons:

```
def click_on_link
  Watir::Wait.until { self.the_link_element.element.enabled? }
  self.the_link
end
```

...but does not work with the link. I made it work determining if the attribute exists, this way:

```
def click_on_proceed_form
  Watir::Wait.until { !self.the_link_element.element.attribute_value('disabled') }
  self.proceed_form_submit
end
```

Looking for the "enabled?" method at the [Watir documentation here](http://wtr.rubyforge.org/rdoc/1.6.2/classes/Watir/Element.html) or at the [Page-Object gem here](http://rubydoc.info/github/cheezy/page-object/master/frames), it seems that is available for all elements. But looking for the same method in the [Watir documentation here](http://rubydoc.info/github/watir/watir-webdriver/master/frames), seems it's only available for Buttons, Selects and Inputs.

So, i wonder is there is an "enabled?" method for links (anchors) and, if it exists, how to use it. Can you help clarify this issue, please? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Watir-webdriver does not support the `enabled?` method for links. I believe this is because the `disabled` attribute is not a standard attribute for links.

On the other hand, Watir-classic does support the `enabled?` method for links. However, it will always return `false` (again because links cannot be disabled).

Therefore, I think your approach is correct (unless you want to monkey patch the link elements to support the `enabled?`).

However, you should try to avoid using Watir-webdriver directly where possible. The page-object gem has its own methods for waiting and getting attribute values:

```
def click_on_proceed_form
  wait_until{ !the_link_element.attribute('disabled') }
  proceed_form_submit
end
```

Comment: It works fine with wait_until, thanks! I'll upgrade the other pages. But i need to call the element with "_element.element" to avoid a "Deprecated use" warning. Also here, you're right, the "self." are not required. But i must use them for example to fill text fields, like:
self.first_name = 'John Doh' ...and i'm not sure why. I'll try to get a reason on the net and if found nothing, i'll post another question. Thank you again!

Comment: The self. here is not required because there are not any equal method, which requires a receiver so they are not mistaken for local variable assignment.

Comment: You should not get a deprecated warning without the `.element`. Make sure you are using the method `attribute` not `attribute_value`.

Comment: Exactly, i was using `attribute_value` and this is why i get the deprecated warning. With `attribute` there are no warnings.